# Parameters for VAC 5046-X005 gate pulse transformer

Tags: transformer, identification, pulse, gate-driving, igbt

I'm trying to parameterize this device to find a suitable equivalent. Trouble is, there seems to be no datasheet available, and one of the two secondaries are measuring open, so complete measurements are not possible. The manufacturer has the [5046-X006](https://vacuumschmelze.com/Assets-Web/5046-X006.pdf) datasheet, but nothing for the X005.

- Primary and one secondary measure 1.0Ω DCR
- With good secondary open, primary measures 3.61mH / 143Ω (LCR meter)
- With primary open, good secondary measures 3.9mH / 143Ω
- With good secondary shorted, primary measures 0.02mH / 1Ω
- With primary shorted, good secondary measures 0.03mH / 1Ω

[image: Vacuumschmelze 5046-X005 gate pulse transformer]

From what I can gather, the ratio is 1:1.1:1.1. Two of these are present in parallel and they function as 140kHz power switch-mode transformers. They are driven from unipolar 24vDC and clamped to -24vDC. Here is a primary waveform in-circuit:

[image: Primary of VAC 5042-X005]

[This Vacuumschmelze document](https://www.vacuumschmelze.com/Assets-Web/PI-IA_4.pdf) lists their modern devices and none are rated for >100kHz, whereas the X006 (closest datasheet I could find) is rated for 130kHz. But only the X100 (L=1.4mH) and X008 (through-hole, 18v/100kHz) are available from Mouser...

Is this a lost cause?

Comment: Don't give up there are faster pulse transformers to be found

Comment: I work in marketing at VAC and like to leave a short comment: of course, VAC has data-sheets for all products they manufacture. As the item in the photo is a customer specific product, it cannot be published. I would suggest that you contact the manufacturer of the device, this transformer was built in. They should be able to help you.
Best wishes and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be labelled the same as a '5046×005 Transformers 10 nos Siemens S120'
These are advertised online by a number of sellers.
One example can be found [here](https://www.newbecca.com/product/541407180629)

Answer (score 1):

I disassembled this transformer and determined its following data: primary winding - 27 turns, wire diameter 0.11, two secondary windings, each with 30 turns, wire diameter 0.1. The outer diameter of the ferrite ring is 9 mm, the inner diameter is 6 mm, and the height of the ring is 5 mm.

Comment: 0.11 and 0.1 mm?